# Trying to insert 1_000_000 records in db using Ecto Elixir

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am trying to insert `1_000_000` records in DB using `Ecto.Multi.new`.

```
alias Remote.Repo

datetime = DateTime.utc_now()

Enum.map(1..1_000_000, fn _x -> %{points: 0, inserted_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime} end)
|> Enum.chunk_every(65535)
|> Enum.each(fn rows ->
  Ecto.Multi.new()
  |> Ecto.Multi.insert_all(:insert_all, Users, rows)
  |> Remote.Repo.transaction()
end)
```

the above is the total code. when I was not using `Enum.chunk_every/2` it was throwing me error as

```
** (Postgrex.QueryError) postgresql protocol can not handle 1000000 parameters, the maximum is 65535
```

but then I started to use `|> Enum.chunk_every(65535)` now it throws error as

```
** (Postgrex.QueryError) postgresql protocol can not handle 196605 parameters, the maximum is 65535
```

now I am using `|> Enum.chunk_every(6000)` and it's working fine.

Questions:

1. Is this the right behaviour for `Enum.chunk_every/2` ?
2. Is it the right and fastest way to insert data in DB?
3. Can you suggest a faster way than this to insert rows to DB?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why it's not doing this for your attempt without `Enum.chunk_every/2`, but 196605 is 3 x 65535, and you have 3 columns to which you're writing. If you change your chunk size to 21845, that should be 65535 params per chunk. I believe that's why `chunk_every/2` looks like it's wrong (1).

As far as I'm aware `insert_all` is the fastest way to insert a batch (2 & 3), though there may be alternatives if all your rows look the same. You could maybe get better performance spinning up tasks for each chunk (up to your repo pool size), but without measuring I couldn't say.

Answer (score 1):

To insert same row into DB you can use raw SQL. We can generate data to insert from select creating data we need and multiply it with [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) function.

This way we will be generating just one query to DB and don't need to transfer 3kk values.

```
query = """
INSERT INTO users (points, inserted_at, updated_at)
SELECT
   0, now(), now()
FROM
   generate_series(1, 1000000);
"""

Ecto.Adapters.SQL.query!(Remote.Repo, query, [])
```